# Коммутатор Avaya как войти через консоль (ctrl+Y)?

Tags: коммутатор

Конфигурировал коммутатор, и забыл, что у данной компании есть "замечательная" функция автосохранения, каждой введённой строки. Какую-то команду ввел не слишком видать корректно и теперь коммутатор не пускает дальше.
Т.е. он не реагирует на Ctrl+Y
Кто как выходил из данной ситуации?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спрошу сразу очевидную вещь ctrl+y и нажимали и вводили?

Comment: @mesfex, как понять вводил? При нормальной ситуации он после ctrl+Y должен дать строки ввода логина и пароля, для входа в CLI.  
А именно этот не реагирует ни как. Вот до этой надписи прогружает себя и всё.